# How can I plant crops automatically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to plant crops automatically? It may help to build an automatic farm. Perhaps with a hopper or a dropper. Anyway, I already use a system for harvesting with water,but I just need help with planting. Does anybody has an idea? No mods,please.

Comment: This would be far easier with MineFactory Reloaded. Do you want this in pure vanilla or are you open to using mods?

Comment: In Vanilla,please. @imulsion

Comment: Villagers can plant crops and they do so even outside of their village. Search for some tutorial on a fully automatic villager crop farm by one of the major Minecraft YouTubers.

Comment: I don't feel as if this is a duplicate. The linked question asks if planting crops is a function of dispensers, to which the answer is no, and this question asks how plants crops can be automatically planted, and there is an answer to this. Replying to the linked question with an answer to this question doesn't really seem logical given what that OP is asking. In the same way, asking if snowballs can damage the wither isn't the same as asking how to defeat the wither.

Comment: @colorfusion It is, apparently, enough of a duplicate that the asker has confirmed it.  That's good enough for me.